# use observer to detect when an element appears

Tags: javascript, dom

Hi,

I want to get the text from an element that wont appear in the DOM until the user hovers another element so I added an observer but I still get an error that says TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null.

This is my code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
// Select the node that will be observed for mutations
var parentOfMyList = document.body;

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
var callback = function(mutationsList) {
    for(var mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
            var lists = document.getElementById("list").textContent;
            console.log(lists)
        }
    }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(parentOfMyList, config);   
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you're making some other DOM modification before adding `list`.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: unfortunate it cant be minimal because its quite a complex code. The problem seems to be that "body" wont appear until later so I added the observer but still no use.

Comment: Seems like you just need to check whether `getElementById()` returns anything before trying to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the element exists before trying to use it.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  // Select the node that will be observed for mutations
  var parentOfMyList = document.body;

  // Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
  var config = {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
  };

  // Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
  var callback = function(mutationsList) {
    for (var mutation of mutationsList) {
      if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
        var elt = document.getElementById("list");
        if (elt) {
          var lists = elt.textContent;
          alert(lists);
        }
      }
    }
  };

  // Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
  var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
  observer.observe(parentOfMyList, config);

  var container = document.querySelector("#container");
  document.querySelector("#b1").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var l = document.createElement("div");
    l.id = "list";
    l.textContent = "This is the list";
    container.appendChild(l);
  });

  document.querySelector("#b2").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var l = document.createElement("div");
    l.id = "list2";
    l.textContent = "This is list #2";
    container.appendChild(l);
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#list1 {
  background-color: green;
}

#list2 {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<button id="b1">Click to create list</button>
<br>
<button id="b2">Click to create list2</button>
```

Comment: I tried but it didnt work. No errors but no logs are shown either.

Comment: I've added a stack snippet showing that it works. So the problem must be elsewhere in your application. Are you sure it's creating an element with that ID?

Comment: It does exists. This last code you posted pretty much works. Only one little detail, I changed the line `alert(lists);` to `console.log(lists);` and I get the log twice instead of once. Why does that happen?

Comment: I used `alert()` here because the emulated console in the Stack Snippet is also a DOM element, so I was getting a loop when the mutation observer caused another mutation.

Comment: I don't know why you got a doubled log in your code, though.

Comment: I updated my question with the code exactly as I am using it. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't do that. Now my answer no longer makes sense, since the original, broken code is gone. And it no longer gets the error message mentioned in the text.

Comment: I created a fiddle that uses `console.log`, I only get one message every time I click. https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/qhbyLvzd/3/

Comment: If there are two `childList` items in `mutationList`, you'll get two log messages, because of the `for` loop. So I guess it depends on what changes you're making that trigger the mutation event.

Comment: Okay sorry, I didnt mean it. I just wanted to show you the code as I am using it. Its pretty much the same but I am getting the log twice. Maybe its another code in my page that is interfering?

Comment: Remember you'll keep getting the log message every time the DOM changes. It's not testing whether the current change involves the `list` element.

Comment: I see. I thought it would only change when the `list` element will change. Then i will be getting a lot of log messages??

Comment: You could change the criteria you use for when to log. You log any time there's a `childList` mutation anywhere. Perhaps you should also check whether `mutation.target.id == "list"`.

Comment: You could also attach your observer to something more specific than `document`.

Comment: Something more specific than document means the parent of "list"?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: The problem is that the element has no parent. Thats why I got to use body. Unfortunately I cant change that because I dont have control over the html.

Comment: What exact mutation event are you trying to catch? If it's just the addition of the `list` element, check `mutation.addedNodes[0].id == "list"`.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord for all the information in the `MutationRecord` object.

Comment: I want to catch the `list` element because its the one that contains the text I need.

Comment: But what about the list element? Just the first addition? You can use `observer.disconnect()` when you get the first event.

Comment: Yes, as soon as the element appears once that would be it.

Comment: Sorry i need your help again. Right below `var lists = elt.textContent;` I added these lines of code: `const sounds = lists.toLowerCase().split('    ').reduce((accum, str) => {
    const name = str.match(/^([^ ]+)/)[0];
    accum[name] = { url: '/../flashsound/' + name + '.mp3' };
    return accum;
     }, {});` but its catching an empty string, despite the log show it right.

Comment: Is this related to your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50320851/how-to-use-a-variable-declared-in-another-function? The problem there seems to be that you're calling `playthis()` before the mutation occurs, so `lists` hasn't been assigned yet.

Comment: Yes, its related. But I have `playthis()` placed after the mutation occurs.

Comment: Please see this https://fiddle.jshell.net/cmnfjckw/ some functions names are changed but I think you can figure out which is which.

Comment: There's no HTML there, what's it supposed to do? Anyway, if you have a different problem, post a new question.

Comment: `console.log(lists);` should show the string. I cant post the html there because its very complex. Thats the problem with this. The html wont show right away and thats where `lists` gets its content from. The mutation detects when the content appears in the code and gets the string.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "its catching an empty string, despite the log show it right". And since there's no HTML in the fiddle, the code doesn't do anything, so I can't see the problem occurring.

Comment: There was too much code in the fiddle for me to know where to look for the issue.

Comment: Maybe you want to see it on the actual page? But the amount of code is the same.

Comment: You need to ask a new question and provide a proper [mcve] for this part of the problem.

Comment: Okay, I did https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50403478/using-mutation-observer-and-variables I simplified the code so I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Could you please take a look at it?