# How to use a variable declared in another function

Tags: jquery, global-variables

Hi,

I want to make global a variable called "lists" and declare its value on this function so I can use it on another function as well:

```
   var lists;
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var parentOfMyList = document.body;
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
  };

  var callback = function(mutationsList) {
    for (var mutation of mutationsList) {
      if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
        var elt = document.getElementById("contents");
        if (elt) {
          lists = elt.textContent;
          console.log(lists);
          observer.disconnect();
        }
      }
    }
  };
  var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
  observer.observe(parentOfMyList, config);
});
```

this other function:

```
function playthis() {
 const input = lists;
 const sounds = input.toLowerCase();
 console.log(sounds);
}
```

I tried by removing "var" before the variable "lists" but it didnt work. It says "input" is undefined. Whats wrong?

Thank you

Comment: `lists` won't updated before the click run it will gives you undefined .. if you try it after click it'll work fine *if the `lists` variable updated on click* .. so to avoid undefined before click you can use `var lists = '';`  you can see it here https://jsfiddle.net/v01cg52e/

Comment: I did that but then the log outputs nothing.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you doing `const input = lists;`? Can't you just `const sounds = lists.toLowerCase();`. If the variable wasn't global, you'd get an error on `const input = lists;`. Are you sure the variable is a string? Try add `console.log(typeof lists)` at the top of `function playthis`

Comment: Im just simplifying it because the second function is way more complex.

Comment: Sure, but the example you posted looks sound, so perhaps the modifications you did for the post fix the issue? Have you tried the `console.log(typeof lists)`? and maybe add `console.log(lists)`. Are you sure the data that's supposed to be there in there is there?

Comment: So what's the output of the `console.log`'s? Are you sure `var lists;` is at the highest level?

Comment: Yes, lists is on top of everything. The log outputs undefined.

Comment: What happens when you add `var something = "something";` under `var lists;` and in `function playthis`, you add `console.log(something);`?

Comment: it says something. That one is fine because the variable is declared within the same function.

Comment: If that output does say "something" with my example, it means that either there is a scope issue, you have a "casing typo" or you are doing a `delete lists` somewhere. Either way, without a live example, I don't think it's possible to fix your error without knowing. If my example works fine, it's something in your code that you haven't posted

Comment: but keep in mind `something` is being defined outside any functions whereas `lists` is not.

Comment: Then move `lists` out also, to make it global

Comment: lists is already declared outside on the top of everything but its value has to be defined by the first function.

Answer (score -1):

You must need to define Global Variable in Global Scope. I am not able to connect with last }); in your first code section. it does not tell whether var lists is in some code block or declared globally outside. if you can post complete code it will be easy to see its scope with respect to function you are calling it in. I mean Put it before `$(document).ready(function() {`. If you have shown complete code then it would be easy to detect. Please try below code -

```
//Globally Defined
var lists;

$(document).ready(function() {


   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var parentOfMyList = document.body;
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
  };

  var callback = function(mutationsList) {
    for (var mutation of mutationsList) {
      if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
        var elt = document.getElementById("contents");
        if (elt) {
          lists = elt.textContent;
          console.log(lists);
          observer.disconnect();
        }
      }
    }
  };
  var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
  observer.observe(parentOfMyList, config);
});

function playthis() {
 const input = lists;
 const sounds = input.toLowerCase();
 console.log(sounds);
}
```

If this does not solve your problem please do below changes to code. I want to see data at few places.

```
var callback = function(mutationsList) {

    // In case mutationsList if JSON Object Otherwise just console mutationsList
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
    for (var mutation of mutationsList) {
      if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
        var elt = document.getElementById("contents");
        console.log(elt);
        if (elt) {

          lists = elt.textContent;
          console.log(lists);
          observer.disconnect();
        }
      }
    }
};
```

Comment: How do you just dream up that the user has `$(document).ready(function() {` around 1 function, but the other is not?

Comment: I wrapped up the entire code in `$(document).ready(function() {` but it still wont work

Comment: @CainNuke Can you post complete code that can show placement of both sections of your code

Comment: i am not able to connect with last }); in your first code section. it does not tel whether var lists is in some code block or declared globally outside. if you can post complete code it will be easy to see its scope with respect to function you are calling it in.

Comment: @CainNuke can you please show me result of console.log(mutationsList). you need to put it after below line of code - var callback = function(mutationsList) {

Comment: its okay now. I solved by putting everything inside `if (mutation.type == 'childList') {` thank you. By the way, I would appreciate your help in my previous question which is related to this and Im stuck with.

Comment: Okay. Thank you.